# ListView and ViewPager within Fragment with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

I am trying to implement both of these features into a Fragment but so far no success. It shows me error `Cannot resolve method findViewById`in both `ListView` and `ViewPager` also a `Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categoria)`  What I am trying to do is enter from my `IntroActivity.java` to `FmMenu.java` and navigate to my other fragment `FmContact.java` with Navigation Drawer that is located in a separate class that is `MenuActivity.java`.

**This is my FmMenu.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by WiLo on 2/13/2015.
 */
public class FmMenu extends Fragment {

    String[] categoria = {
            "Jeans"
    };

    int[] imagenes = {
            R.drawable.veroxjeans1,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans2,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans3,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans4,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans5,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans6,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans7
    };

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_menufragment, container, false);



        //lista
        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categoria);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        //galeria de imagenes

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[0]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[1]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[2]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[3]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[4]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[5]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[6]));

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        return rootView;

    }

    /**@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lay_menufragment);


    }**/

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        List<Fragment> fragmentos;
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fragmentos = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        }

        public void addfragments(Fragment xfragment){
            fragmentos.add(xfragment);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragmentos.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentos.size();
        }
    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_IMAGE = "imagen";
        private int imagen;

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int imagen) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_IMAGE, imagen);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if(getArguments() != null) {
                imagen = getArguments().getInt(ARG_IMAGE);
            }
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

            ImageView imagenView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imagenView.setImageResource(imagen);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

**This is my IntroActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;

/**
 * Created by WiLo on 2/13/2015.
 */
public class IntroActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        /*getActionBar().hide();*/
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);
        Log.i("BunBunUp", "MainActivity Created");
    }

    /**@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_intro, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }**/

    public void startMenuActivity(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("BunBunUp", "IntroActivity Resumed");
    }

    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("BunBunUp", "IntroActivity Paused");
    }

    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("BunBunUp", "IntroActivity Stopped");
    }
}
```

**Any help would be appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to its View object (rootView) to call the method like:

```
ListView lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

I am assuming that **lay_menufragment** xml contains listView1 as an ID to the ListView element.
Fix the other similar compile error the same way.

I don't see how you're launching FmMenu fragment maybe via Intent, layout, or whatever. Please post the layout file(s) also like lay_menufragment, to save time.

Comment: Thanks for the help... needed to add `rootView`

Comment: You're welcome. From your question, I finally noticed that you can call findViewById in the MainActivity without the View object because it implements a View.